# Getting the schema in swashbuck when using HttpResponseMessage, in WebApi

Tags: asp.net-web-api

I'm attempting to use [Swashbuckle](https://github.com/domaindrivendev/Swashbuckle) to generate a swagger inteface for our API, we're returning `HttpResponseMessage` in our controller methods.

The docs indicate to use the `[ResponseType(…)]` attribute to indicate the actual return type. But that attribute is restricted to .net 4.5 (I believe, will gladly be proven wrong), and won't work in a .net4 project.

There are the XML comments, however I couldn't see how to use them the generate the schema information (I've taken a look through the unit tests in the project, but couldn't figure out if it's supported)